# Build failing when working with strict mode in tsconfig for spring-flo, jointjs, code-mirror

Tags: typescript, codemirror, jointjs, tsconfig

When `tsconfig.json` has strict mode on, when doing `ng serve` spring-flow dependencies throws error for code-mirror and Model

[image]

[image]

What can be done here.

Answer (score 1):

Converting it to skipLibCheck and skipDefaultLibCheck to true works as required.

[image]